# Generic list/sublist handling

Tags: c#, generics

Let's say we have a class

```
class ComplexCls
{
  public int Fld1;
  public string Fld2;
  //could be more fields
}

class Cls
{
  public int SomeField;
}
```

and then some code

```
class ComplexClsList: List<ComplexCls>;
ComplexClsList myComplexList;
// fill myComplexList

// same for Cls    
class ClsList : List<Cls>;
ClsList myClsList;
```

We want to populate myClsList from myComplexList, something like (pseudocode):

```
foreach Complexitem in myComplexList
{
  Cls ClsItem = new Cls();
  ClsItem.SomeField = ComplexItem.Fld1;
}
```

The code to do this is easy and will be put in some method in myClsList.
However I'd like to design this as generic as possible, for generic ComplexCls.
Note that the exact ComplexCls is known at the moment of using this code, only the algorithm shd be generic.
I know it can be done using (direct) reflection but is there other solution?
Let me know if the question is not clear enough. (probably isn't).
[EDIT] Basically, what I need is this: having myClsList, I need to specify a DataSource (ComplexClsList) and a field from that DataSource (Fld1) that will be used to populate my SomeField

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for AutoMapper

Comment: You've taken away the ability for a generic solution when you inherited from `List<ComplexCls>`. I think we need more details..

Comment: I just edited my question, please read it again. You guys are fast !

Comment: @SLaks: I am looking now at AutoMapper. Seems interesting. Thanks!

Comment: Is the type of `SomeField` on `Cls` always going to be `int`?

Comment: @Jeff: for starters we can assume it's always int or other fixed type. We may try later use a generic type if doesn't add too much complexity

Answer (score 4):

This is just a mapping, so use some simple LINQ:

```
ClsList myClsList = new ClsList();
myClsList.AddRange(
  myComplexList.Select(Complexitem => new Cls { SomeField = Complexitem.Fld1 })
);
```

Comment: `.ToList()` doesn't return a `ClsList`

Comment: Unless `ClsList` has some functionality, it'd probably more sense for the OP to just go with `IEnumerable<Cls>`...

Comment: Yep, that looks good. But how can we more generic: I'd like to use a generic (but known at the moment of call) ComplexClass, which has an unknown yet int field (Fld1) to map on a (possible) unknown target field (SomeField). Something like:
public void MapField<TSourceList>(TSourceList SourceList, string SourceFieldName, string TargetFieldName)
except I'd like to not use field names if possible

Comment: @Jeff: ClsList has the functionality I described above

Comment: @user628661 Check out the answer I just posted, it might fit your needs.

Answer (score 2):

Okay, the easier version assuming we have a known target field on a class (I've written this as an extension method, no need to do

```
public IEnumerable<Cls> MapField<TSource>(IEnumerable<TSource> sourceList, 
                                          Func<TSource, int> sourceSelector)
{
  return sourceList.Select(x => new Cls {SomeField = sourceSelector(x)});
}
```

Called this way

```
IEnumerable<Cls> result = MapField(myComplexList, x => x.Fld1);
```

*Aside:* Since your `myComplexList` of type `ComplexClsList` inherits from `List` (which implements `IEnumerable` this will work. The result isn't of type `ClsList` that you wanted, but you could easily call `.ToList()` on the result and provide a constructor on `ClsList` that takes a `List<Cls>`.

---

And the more complicated version for when we don't know the target field (or type)...

```
public IEnumerable<TResult> MapField<TSource, TResult, TMap>(
    IEnumerable<TSource> sourceList, 
    Func<TSource, TMap> sourceSelector,
    Func<TMap, TResult> resultCreator)
{
    return sourceList.Select(x => resultCreator(sourceSelector(x)));
}
```

Not as pretty to call....

```
IEnumerable<Cls> result = MapField(
    myComplexList,
    source => source.Fld1,
    valueToMap => new Cls() {SomeField = valueToMap});
```

Might be a better way, but it's not occurring to me at the moment.

Edit: Actually, you could combine the two `Func` on the last one into a single one that takes a `TSource` and creates and maps the necessary fields to `TResult`, but I'm really not sure what you're gaining with that extra layer of abstraction...

Comment: ... the irony being that after all this effort, calling the MapField method is just as complicated and repetitive as the LINQ code that it was meant to replace.

Comment: Hehe... hmm, back to AutoMapper? ;)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to reconsider extending `List` classes in the first place. What does inheritance give you, in this case? I suspect that you'll be better off favoring [composition over inheritance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) here. One possible approach would be:

```
// If you would say that a ComplexCls "is a" Cls, then maybe your inheritance
// relationship belongs here instead.
public class ComplexCls : Cls { 
}

public class ClsList
{
  public IReadOnlyCollection<Cls> Items {get;set;}
}

public class ComplexClsList
{
  public IReadOnlyCollection<ComplexCls> Items {get;set;}
}
```

Then you can create a ClsClist easily.

```
ClsList basicList = new ClsList{Items = complexList.Items};
```

But you may want to take it a step farther and question why the `ClsList` and `ComplexClsList` classes exist at all. Why not simply pass around `List`s directly. I mean, what's the difference between a `ClsList` and a "List of Clses" (`List<Cls>`)?

Comment: `ComplexCls` and `Cls` are not compatible types, here, so you'll have to do something other than copying the reference to `Items`

Comment: I am thinking that I can put this mapping functionality in a base class for ClsList so I can just reuse it every time I have a new ClsList class derived from ClsListBase and not have to write the code again

Comment: @user628661: You don't have to use inheritance in order to avoid duplicating code. Utility methods don't have to be in a base class. What specific benefit are you deriving from having special list classes?

Comment: @StriplingWarrior: yes, it's just more convenient if it's in base class and working only on internal stuff. But that's not the problem, it can be anywhere if that helps, building the function is the really hard thing

Comment: @user628661: My point is that building the function would be a lot easier if you stopped inheriting from the `List<>` interface.